# How can I move my MSYS2 folder to another folder (both in the D driver) if possible?

Tags: sdl-2, mingw-w64, msys2

My files are quite messy, so I decided to try to organize some program files I use to code C++ in Visual Studio while using the SDL2 library, I've successfully moved ACLib and Gnu, and the code run as expected, I could compile the program. Then I moved the `MSYS2` file, when I tried compiling the program, which I do by typing `make` in a terminal and proceeding to type `./main`, it told me:

```
g++ -I src/include -L src/lib -o main main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, g++ -I src/include -L src/lib -o main main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I was devastated by the error and desperately tried everything I could, including editing the "environment variables" to solve this issue but to no avail, I gave up and decided to simply return the `MSYS2` to its original place, expecting some other kind of error along the lines of "could not find such file or directory" but no, my code compiled without any errors, even without changing back the environment variables.

It's not crucial for me to move the MSYS2 file so I'll be patient but I'd happily want to see your possible solutions and give more information if necessary, here are some links for my installation process:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oC69vlWofJQ
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUZZC9UXyFs&t=615s

I installed `MSYS2` on `D:/usr/Downloads`
and tried to move it to `D:/usr/Programs`

Comment: I'm not sure if you can savely move the folder or not, I'd just reinstall it in the right location.

Comment: Also links to external resources like youtube is not a suggested or supported question format.  Its much more useful to someone trying to help to copy and paste the broken code and try to fix it, no one has the time to go watch someone elses videos and give them clicks.  Embeded screen shots of non-typeable things would be a better method.

Comment: @easleyfixed I'll surely work on avoiding those youtube links and instead just write the procexs, but also this hasn't involved code that needs to be fixed apart from maybe writing "make" on the command prompt and other commands, thank you for your recommendation!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that's just what I am trying to avoid, but if I don't get any satisfactory answers, I might just do the whole instalation process again...